# MS Flow - Create Event (V2) on another calendar with Send As permission

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, exchange-server, power-automate

I am running into an issue with Microsoft Flow to create appointments on another calendar that my account as Send As permission to. I am able to create appointments in the UI for this second account. However in Flow, it is asking for a CalendarID. The drop down only shows calendars directly related to the account in the connection. When I manually enter the CalendarID to the second account, I receive this error: "The specified object was not found in the store."

Any help / tutorials will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > "The specified object was not found in the store."

This is an EWS permissions error so whatever you doing isn't going to work with SendAS rights. You will need to assign full access permission to the Mailbox (or at least rights to the calendar folder via Add-MailboxFolderPermission) for this to work with EWS. SendAs permission by definition only gives a user rights to SendAS another user not access folders in their Mailbox. You can test all this with the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ which is going to be making the same calls. If it works in the EWSEditor with the same creds as flow but not in your other code then you know the rights are good but whatever you doing in Flow is the issue.